# How to get mysqli to read a mysql cnf file

Tags: php, mysqli

From the command line, one can get **mysql** and **mysqldump** to read a config file using `--defaults-extra-file`.  This can contain username and password for connection.

Is there a way to get **mysqli** from **php** to read a similar file?  I know I could just read it and parse it, but that destroys its protection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file can be read in using the **options** function

**Using a procedure**

```php
mysqli_options($con, MYSQLI_READ_DEFAULT_FILE, "myfile.cnf");
```

From [PHP mysqli options() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_options.asp)

**Using a class**

```php
 $this->options (MYSQLI_READ_DEFAULT_FILE,'file.cnf')
```

From [mysqli::options](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.options.php)